# jQuery extracting text from DIV with img tag

Tags: jquery

I want to extract text from the following HTML:

```
<div class="text_with_icon"> my text <img src="https://example.com/logo.png" alt="mylogo"> </div>
```

I try to simply use '.text()':

```
my_data = $('div.text_with_icon').text();
$('div.my_output_class').text(my_data);
```

But the output on website is such plain text:

```
my text <img src="https://example.com/logo.png" alt="mylogo">
```

Snippet below:

```js
my_data = $('div.text_with_icon').text();
$('div.my_output_class').text(my_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text_with_icon"> my text <img src="https://example.com/logo.png" alt="mylogo"> </div>

<div class="my_output_class"></div>
```

How can I make the output be simply "my text"?

Comment: No, it doesn't? https://jsfiddle.net/Lmrko2dj/

Comment: My mistake, it came out there was `noscript` tag in div.  The div which I posted was HTML result of changing from `text` to `html` in my 2nd line and therefore already converted to text, leaving contents of <noscript> tag only. As provided div HTML is incorrect, should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

you don not have to use "div.text_with_icon".

follow below code, by this code you will get only text.  "my text"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var text1=$(".text_with_icon").text();
alert(text1); //alert
console.log(text1); //console (press f12 to see returned value on console)
});
```